# Python3 Dictionary - replacing contents issue

Tags: python-3.x

I'm actually working for project to myself, just to learn, I'm aware this project is weak since anyone that sees the file could see the source, and it was no encryption, but here is my doubt:

This is my code:

```
defaultusername = "Alex"
defaultpassword = "asd123"


inputusername = input("Introduce tu username: ")
inputpassword = input("Introduce la contraseña: ")

credenciales = {'ID': 1, 'plataforma' : 'steam', 'username' : 'asd', 'password' : 'password',
                'ID': 2, 'plataforma' : 'steam2', 'username2' : 'asd2', 'password' : 'password2'}


if inputusername == defaultusername and inputpassword == defaultpassword:
    opcion = int(input('''
1) Consultar mis credenciales
2) Añadir credenciales (u/e:p)
3) Borrar credenciales

Selecciona una opción: '''))

    if opcion == 1:
        print("Credenciales:")
        for i in range(credenciales['ID']):
            print(credenciales['plataforma'],">",credenciales['username'].strip() + ":".strip() + credenciales['password'])
    elif opcion == 2:
        pass
    elif opcion == 3:
        pass
    else:
        print("Selecciona una opción correcta")


else:
    print("Datos incorrectos")
```

The results only prints the second line of the dictionary (pretty sure the content is replaced once adding an extra line on dictionaries but I'm not sure how to fix this, any help is appreciated!)

Result:

```
Selecciona una opción: 1
Credenciales:
steam2 > asd:password2
steam2 > asd:password2
```

Comment: keys in a dictionary must be unique. here you have written keys `ID`, `platforma` and `password` twice. so tha value of ID is 2 you then loop and print that twice

Comment: add this line after you create your dictionary and you will see `print(credenciales)`

Answer (score 0):

keys in python dictionarys must be unique. in your dictionary you have defined the keys `ID`, `platforma` and `password` are defined twice in the dict, as the dict key must be unique you end up overwritting the value of these keys.

```py
credenciales = {'ID': 1, 'plataforma' : 'steam', 'username' : 'asd', 'password' : 'password',
                'ID': 2, 'plataforma' : 'steam2', 'username2' : 'asd2', 'password' : 'password2'}

print(credenciales)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'ID': 2, 'plataforma': 'steam2', 'username': 'asd', 'password': 'password2', 'username2': 'asd2'}
```

So you need to maybe reconsider your data structure for how to store this info. maybe a list of dicts or a dict of dicts based on the id number.